# I want to add / remove class on lable tag

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my Javascript code

```
$('.lable_item').click(function () {
   if (!$(this).hasClass('label_act')) {
       $(this).addClass('label_act');
   } else {
       $(this).removeClass('label_act');
   }
```

});

Here is my HTML Content

```
< div class="layout">
   <label class="lable_item">< input type="checkbox" />label< /label>
   <label class="lable_item label_act"><input type="checkbox" />label< /label>
   <label class="lable_item"><input type="checkbox" />label< /label>
</div>
```

I want to add / remove class on lable tag.If label has "label_act", then it will be remove otherwise add class "label_act"

Comment: Maybe try toggleClass function [link](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: Same homework as dharmesh.ajani ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant I would say another account for the same person. This is the exact same question.

Comment: No need to ask it a third time then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change javascript as per below

```
$('.lable_item input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
           $(this).parent('.lable_item').addClass('label_act');
    }else{
           $(this).parent('.lable_item').removeClass('label_act');
    }
});
```

change HTML As per below. It's working.

```
<div class="layout">
   <label class="lable_item" for="c1"><input type="checkbox" id="c1" />label</label>
   <label class="lable_item label_act" for="c2"><input type="checkbox" id="c2" />label</label>
   <label class="lable_item" for="c3"><input type="checkbox" id="c3" />label</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) would be useful here.

```
$('.lable_item').click(function () {
     $(this).toggleClass('label_act'); 
 });
```